# Как сделать нижнюю прокрутку для выпирающей таблицы? (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть небольшое по ширине окошко, в которое должна полностью вписаться таблица с нижней прокруткой.

[image: таблица]

На overflow вообще не реагирует.

Как можно сделать прокрутку влево-вправо для этой таблицы, чтобы она не сжималась из-за небольшой ширины?

Фрагмент кода:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="personal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 order-last order-lg-first">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Аккаунт</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Корзина (0)</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-money-check"></i> Мои заказы</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> Настройки</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Список пользователей</li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-list"></i> Список заказов</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-9">
      <div class="table-wrap">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Отчество</th>
      <th scope="col">Дата рождения</th>
      <th scope="col">Номер телефона</th>
      <th scope="col">Город</th>
      <th scope="col">Улица</th>
      <th scope="col">Дом</th>
      <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
      <th scope="col">Статус</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

И CSS:

```
.table {
  min-width: 1000px;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

---

UPD. Проблема решилась добавлением table-wrap, но из решения вытекла новая. Оно начало выпирать (игнорирует padding от бутстрап):

[image: Выпирает]

---

UPD2. Проблему решил добавлением нового div class="table-wrap" вместо div class="col-12 col-lg-9" (код обновил).

Comment: overflow:auto - не работатет?

Comment: Выложите фрагмент кода или дайте ссылку, где можно посмотреть код.

Comment: overflow вообще не работает

Comment: фрагмент кода выложил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно указать overflow не для тега table, а для вашего col-12 col-lg-9. Я бы этому элементу добавил какой-то отдельный селектор, например table-wrap

```
.table-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Помогло, но из этого решения возникла новая проблема